# WCF streaming files

Tags: wcf

I need to pass a memory stream  to the WCF server , how do i need to add this data type in my data contract. 
I will eventually need to convert this to a memory stream and pass it on to my service layer.

```
datacontact[DataMember]

 Stream str = null; 

        public Stream File
        {
            get { return str;   }
            set { str = value;  }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the [WCF Streaming page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx). I'm not really sure if (how) you can do this with a DataContract, the normal way is to specify streams in the OperationContract. Wouldn't that work for you?

Short summary:

- Sender produces the Stream
- Sender does *not* Close the Stream
- Receiver *does* close the stream
- Set the MaxReceivedMessageSize property of the binding to a value larger than the largest item you wish to transfer.